# substr with a custom field in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to use substr function to remove unnecessary characters from a link. 
I'll put an "youtube" input on post editor, but I need to ignore "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" and print only the video ID (such wGoM_wVrwng).

So I tried:

```
<?php
echo substr('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGoM_wVrwng', 32);   
?>
```

But, I need to put an `<?php the_field(); ?>` there. something like

```
<?php
echo substr('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= **THE_FIELD()**', 32);   
?>
```

how to proceed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: echo substr('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.the_field().', 32);? Something like that?

Comment: You can even put the string outside if needed and work on it before putting the substring :)

Comment: thank you Marco, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if (preg_match('%http(?:s)?://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/)(\w*)(&(amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?%', $subject, $regs)) {
      $result = $regs[1];
  } else {
      $result = false;
  }
?>
```

Now if `$result !== false`, it contains that part (the video ID).

Also this would work with and without https, with youtu.be and youtube.com, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds good, but I still need a the_field() that allow user to put the link. How to do that within this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple way if the delimiter i am using is unique.

```
$link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456";

$array = explode("?v=", $link);
var_dump($array);
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'https://www.youtube.com/watch' (length=29)
  1 => string '123456' (length=6)

$sameLink = implode("?v=", $array);
echo $sameLink;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456
```